# My server is not responding to the "Get " request I am making using express.js. And my send() function is also not working

Tags: node.js, express, server, backend, nodemon

This is how my App.js looks:-

```
import express from 'express';
    
    const app = express();
    
    app.get("/", function(req,res){
        console.log(req)
        res.send("My server is responding")
    })
    
    // app.use(express.json());
    
    // app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    //     console.log(req);
    //       res.json("WORKING!!!");
    
    // });
    
    app.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log("The server is listening ");
    });
```

> The commented part here is the things are those which I have already
> tried, "I have also tried old conventional require statements"

```
This is how my package.json looks:-
{
  "name": "weather",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start":"npm start"
  },
  "type":"module",
  "author": "Subhangam Dey",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1"
  }
}
```

Please help out this beginner, I cannot proceed to backend development without making this clear

[Link to code on Github](https://github.com/subhangamdey/MyFistExpressProject)

Answer (score 0):

Change your package.json file scripts section like below and restart the node server, it will work:

```
{
  "name": "weather",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ."
  },
  "type": "module",
  "author": "Subhangam Dey",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1"
  }
}
```

You can also change specifying the index file name: `node App.js` as the start command.